# Why does Qt ColumnView widget crash in this situation?

Tags: qt, user-interface, crash, widget

I'm testing an application in *Qt* that uses a *QColumnView* widget. The widget has two columns and when an item in the first column (parent) is clicked, it's items (children) are shown in the second column.

The problem I'm having is this:

If any parent has more children than there are parents, the application crashes if any of the "excess" children are selected.

In other words, if there are five parents and each parent has five (or less) children, everything is fine. However, if any parent has six or more children, the application crashes if any child with index greater than the the first five is selected.

I hope the above is clear.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a minimal code example

Comment: @pnezis Thanks for the comment. It turns out I needed the following:  

    if(!hasIndex(row, column, parent))    
        return QModelIndex();  

In my "QAbstractItemModel::index()" function. I didn't think the view widget would call "index" with invalid row, column combinations since it can use "QAbstractItemModel::rowCount()" and QAbstractItemModel::columnCount()" to get the structure of the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I needed the following:

```
if(!hasIndex(row, column, parent))  
    return QModelIndex();
```

In my "QAbstractItemModel::index()" function. I didn't think the view widget would call "index()" with out of bound row/column combinations since it can use "QAbstractItemModel::rowCount()" and QAbstractItemModel::columnCount()" to get the structure of the model.